# How to add custom opacity values to colors in tailwind css themes

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to learn how to do themes in tailwind CSS for a laravel project. Stuck on how to add opacity in the theme

```css
//app.css file

@layer base {
    :root {
        /* Brand Color */
        --color-element-primary: #5754FF;
        --color-element-soft-hover: #5754FF; /* 15% */

        /* Text */
        --color-text-primary: #FFFFFF;
        --color-text-content:#FFFFFF; /* 80% */
        --color-text-muted:#7C879F; /* 45% */
```

Than in the `tailwind.config.js` file I setup things like this

```js
extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ["General Sans", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            colors: {
                theme: {
                    'primary': 'var(--color-element-primary)',
                    'primary-soft-hover': 'var(--color-element-primary-soft-hover)',

                }
            },
            textColor: {
                theme: {
                    primary: 'var(--color-text-primary)',
                    content: 'var(--color-text-content)',
                    muted: 'var(--color-text-muted)',
                }
            },
```

This allows me to use it inside the project like this
[image]

But I want to make the opacity values dynamic to the themes. Any insight on how to set this up is much appreciated :)

Comment: Look in to <alpha-value> on this page: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking to use the a theme color with opacity utilities (like `bg-primary/25`) from the framework. Not sure if that is the question here?

In case it is I came across this functions, which works for me:

```
const getColor = (colorVar, { opacityVariable, opacityValue }) => {
  if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
    return `rgb(var(${colorVar})/${opacityValue})`;
  }
  if (opacityVariable !== undefined) {
    return `rgb(var(${colorVar})/var(${opacityVariable}, 1))`;
  }

  return `rgb(var(${colorVar}))`;
};
```

and apply it like so in your source `tailwind.config.js`

```
theme: {
  colors: {
    primary: (params) => getColor("--color-primary", params)
  }
}
```

Now you can define the `--color-primary` variable in your css file and it will change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

as @Gabe pointed out

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables

Need to first convert hex to RGB https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html and set that up in the `app.css`

```
--color-element-primary: 87 84 255;
```

Than in the `tailwind.config.js`

```
'primary': 'rgb(var(--color-element-primary) / .10)',
```